# Silverlight WebRequest/WebClient SecurityException issues with local file system

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I've stumbled across a few sources that state that silverlight cannot execute web requests when running from a local file, ie. using file:// instead of http://.

The problem I have is that we're using a sidebar gadget to host our silverlight app. Previously we were using WCF but now, when trying to include a RESTful json service, we can't due to this restriction.

Is there any workaround for the limitation of not being able to execute web requests when executing silverlight from the filesystem?

**Edit - Update**

I've stumbled across the term Cross-scheme to describe this sort of request, but it doesn't seem like it used to be supported, not sure about Silverlight 4.0. This is catastrophic for us. Any help or workarounds?